# how to rotate text vertically at table column header

Tags: html, css, rotatetransform

I've used this [data table](http://www.datatables.net/) at my webpage. This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxju7/2/) link where I put the code. I want, First Number Second Number column should be vertically rotated. I've made it already. But, problem is **after making it, column header and column can't stay along together.** **Besides this, I want vertical rotated text's column will be as much as possible thinner. But, I can't make it though I set 20px width at that column's header.** Another thing is that, **at IE8, rotated text's div looks different(padding/margin issue)**. According to my question, I should only write about my problem/failure of putting rotating text. But, I've written multiple problems here. That's because, all my problems come after putting rotating text at column header(my given plugin's js is a little bit responsible too as it prevent modifying columns's width properly). I believe, **if I can put the vertical rotated text in proper way(concerning about IE8 too) and modify table's width properly, no problem will be existing anymore**. So, **how can I put the vertical rotate text properly at the column's header**?

Some Code:

```html
<table id="example" class="dataTable display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="rank">Rank</th>
      <th class="wider">User Inserted Title Name</th>
      <th class="rotate">
        <div>Fisrt Number Second Number</div>
      </th>
      <th class="rotate">
        <div>Fisrt Number Second Number</div>
      </th>
      <th class="rotate">
        <div>Fisrt Number Second Number</div>
      </th>
      <th class="rotate">
        <div>Fisrt Number Second Number</div>
      </th>
      <th class="rotate">
        <div>Fisrt Number Second Number</div>
      </th>
      <th class="rotate">
        <div>Fisrt Number Second Number</div>
      </th>
      <th class="rotate">
        <div>Fisrt Number Second Number</div>
      </th>
      <th class="rotate">
        <div>Fisrt Number Second Number</div>
      </th>
      <th class="rotate">
        <div>Fisrt Number Second Number</div>
      </th>
      <th class="rotate">
        <div>Fisrt Number Second Number</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>System Architect and Analyser</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rotate just the div not the table header.Each `th` line should look like:  `<th ><div class="rotate">Fisrt Number Second Number</div></th>`

And adjust the rotate css code to:

```
.rotate {
             filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083);  /* IE6,IE7 */
         -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083)"; /* IE8 */
     -moz-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
      -ms-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* IE9+ */
       -o-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* Safari 3.1+, Chrome */
          transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* Standard */
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tsHunter/fxju7/5/) is an updated fiddle

Comment: Thanks, looking great! Besides this, can you tell me why I can't modify the width of the table's columns? Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fxju7/7/  I want vertical texts will be in two line and their columns will be as much possible as thinner. I've put 20px width of those column's. But, it didn't work!

Comment: at the bottom of `.rotate` there is `width:150px` which is setting it that wide

Comment: No, that's width helps me put those text in two lines. If I don't give it, the text's will be placed 3 or 4 lines. But, I need those in 2 lines. That's why, I gave width: 150px which is working as height actually in terms of vertical text. I guess, you couldn't understand my comment. Now, I'm trying to make it simple. I want, <th class="rotateContent"></th> column's width will be 20px and <th class="wider">User Inserted Title Name</th> column's width will be 120px. But, whatever width I applied by css, the width remains unchanged!

Comment: If you changed the width at the bottom of rotate the width will change. I do understand your comment. If you don't want to change that I will try to find another way.

Comment: yes,20px for 4 lines won't be enough,may be it'll fit 2 lines.That's why,I need all the texts should fit into 2 lines instead of 4 lines. Basically,it shouldn't be 20px.I told 20px as an example to make you understand that how thinner space I want for the number holding cell's.As you see,I use horizontal scrollbar.Hundreds of number holding columns can be placed at the table.That's why,I use vertical 2 line's header text and want to decrease the number holding cell's width too. I think, instead of 20px, 40 or 50px will be perfect to fit the 2 lines vertical header text & number holder's cells

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tsHunter/fxju7/8/) should be what you're looking for. Another layer of `div` with `overflow:visible` allowing it to show the full text without squishing.

Comment: yes, I want this. Thank you so much! But, I don't get solution of another problem. I can't modify other column's width too by css. But, I've told at my post too datatables plugin is responsible for this probably as I've seen some issue at their website. But, I need customizing column's width by css. May be, I'll come another time with this question :) By the way, thanks for your help and I'm ending this question