# Displaying table header content vertically

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

I have this

```
header1 header2

 data1  data2
```

But I want to display it as

```
h       h
e       e 
a       a 
d       d
e       e 
r       r
1       2

data1   data2
```

I also want borders around the headers and table rows.

EDIT:

Based on Vinc199789's answer below I came up with this.

```html
 <table>
  <tr style="border 1px solid;text-align:center;">
     <th style="width:1px;word-break:break-all;border:1px solid;text-align:center;"><div style="width:1px;word-break:break-all;text-align:center;">Jill</div></th>
     <th style="width:1px;word-break:break-all;border: 1px solid;"><div style="width:1px;word-break:break-all;">Smith</div></th>
     <th style="width:1px;word-break:break-all;border: 1px solid;"><div style="width:1px;word-break:break-all;">50</div></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid;">Eve</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid;">Jackson</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid;">94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However I need the following improvements on this:

1. If you see the output, there is a gap above J in "Jill" , "Smith" occupies the entire vertical space and "50" is in the middle. Is there a way to make all the headers start from the ceiling of the vertical space?
2. I also wanted a way to center align "Jill", "Smith" and "50". text-align:center is not working.

Comment: dublicate question , please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335274/how-to-rotate-text-vertically-at-table-column-header

Comment: @Leogout Yes preferably using html only. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use css `word-break: break-all`

What I did is I added a `div` inside a `td` and set the `width` to `1px` (this to make sure that there can not be two letters placed next to each other). I also added `word-break: break-all` and you can see the result in the code snippet or is [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eq5ubgxL/).

**edit**
With `margin-left:auto` and `margin-right:auto` I center the vertical headers and with `text-align:center` I center the other table content.

If you add `vertical-align:top` to the `td` you also have your headers placed at the top

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eq5ubgxL/1/)

```css
td > div{
  width:1px;
  word-break: break-all;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
}
td{
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
 <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
     <td><div>Jill</div></td>
     <td><div>Smith</div></td>
     <td><div>50</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please see the edit to my answer above based on this answer. Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer with the solution to your questions

Comment: Thanks, let me take a look.